# TFS 2017 Work item Extension not working

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

New to this TS scripting so a little help is requested,
I'm trying to create an extension that created a url from 4 work item fields.
example contribution:

```
{
"manifestVersion": 1,
"id": "tritech-tfsurl-control",
"version": "0.1.18",
"name": "tritech-tfsurl-control",
"scopes": [ "vso.work", "vso.work_write" ],
"description": "4 fields to a url",
"publisher": "TriTech-Software-Systems",
"icons": {
    "default": "img/logo.png"
},
"targets": [
    {
        "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
    }
],
"tags": [
    "Work Item",
    "Work Item control",
    "Url",
    "Url tfs server"
],
"content": {
    "details": {
        "path": "details.md"
    }
},
"links": {
    "home": {
        "uri": "http://www.Tritech.com"
    }
},
"branding": {
    "color": "rgb(220, 235, 252)",
    "theme": "light"
},
"files": [
    {
        "path": "img",
        "addressable": true
    },        
    {
        "path": "index.html",
        "addressable": true
    }
],
"categories": [
    "Plan and track"
],
"contributions": [
    {
        "id": "tfsurlcontrol-action",
        "type": "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form-control",
        "description": "Work Item fields to create url from",
        "targets": [
            "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "tfsurl-control",
            "uri": "index.html",
            "height": 90,
            "inputs": [
      {
        "id": "PreviousTFSServer",
        "description": "The TFS server url that has the work item.",
        "type": "WorkItemField",
        "properties": {
          "workItemFieldTypes": [ "String" ]
        },
        "validation": {
          "dataType": "String",
          "isRequired": true
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "TFSCollection",
        "description": "The original tfs collection name",
        "type": "WorkItemField",
        "properties": {
          "workItemFieldTypes": [ "String" ]
        },
        "validation": {
          "dataType": "String",
          "isRequired": true
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "TfsTeamProject",
        "description": "Original TFS project name",
        "type": "WorkItemField",
        "properties": {
          "workItemFieldTypes": [ "String" ]
        },
        "validation": {
          "dataType": "String",
          "isRequired": true
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "TfsWorkItemId",
        "description": "Original work item id",
        "type": "WorkItemField" ,
        "properties": {
          "workItemFieldTypes": [ "Integer" ]
        }          
      }
    ]    
        }
    }
]
```

}

then in my App.ts file is this,

```js
///<reference types="vss-web-extension-sdk" />
import { Controller } from "./control";
import * as ExtensionContracts from "TFS/WorkItemTracking/ExtensionContracts";
import { WorkItemFormService } from "TFS/WorkItemTracking/Services";

var control: Controller;

var provider = () => {
    return {
  onLoaded: (workItemLoadedArgs: ExtensionContracts.IWorkItemLoadedArgs) => {   
            control = new Controller();
        }
    }
};

VSS.register(VSS.getContribution().id, provider);
```

this is my Control.ts file,

`
    private _initialize(): void {

```
    this._inputs = VSS.getConfiguration().witInputs;
    this._ServerFieldName = this._inputs["PreviousTFSServer"];
    this._CollectionFieldName = this._inputs["TFSCollection"];
    this._ProjectFieldName = this._inputs["TFSTeamProject"];
    this._WorkItemIdFieldName =  this._inputs["TfsWorkItemId"];

    WitService.WorkItemFormService.getService().then(
        (service) => {
            Q.spread<any, any>(
                [ service.getFieldValue(this._ServerFieldName),service.getFieldValue(this._CollectionFieldName),
                service.getFieldValue(this._ProjectFieldName),service.getFieldValue(this._WorkItemIdFieldName)],
                (server: string, collection: string, project:string, id: number) => {
                 this._view = new View(server,collection,project,id);
                 }, this._handleError
            ).then(null, this._handleError);
        },
        this._handleError);
}    

private _handleError(error: string): void {
    let errorView = new ErrorView(error);
}
```

}
`
Then I added a view.ts

```js
export class View {

    constructor(server: string, collection: string, project: string, id: number) {
        // container div
        if(server)
        {
            var Container = $("<div />");
            var workItemUrl = $("<span></span>").text("Original work item");
            var a = $("<a> </a>");
            var url = 'server + "/" + collection + "/" + project + "/_workitemId?=" + String(id)'
            a.attr("href", url );
            a.attr("target", "_blank");
            a.text("here.");
            workItemUrl.append(a);
            //$('body').empty().append(Container);
            $(".events").append(workItemUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

```
       <Input Id="PreviousTFSServer" Value="TriTech.Source.Server" />
              <Input Id="TFSCollection" Value="TriTech.Source.Collection" />
              <Input Id="TFSTeamProject" Value="TriTech.Source.Project" />
              <Input Id="TfsWorkItemId" Value="TriTech.Source.Id" />
            </Inputs>
          </ControlContribution>
        </Group>`
```

I started with the latest edition of the vsts-extension-ts-seed-simple-master package. Compiles and creates the extension but I'm not seeing any url or link.

What am I missing?
The WIT has been edited to use the extension.

Web debug shows it is being loaded,

```
{"id":"TriTech-Software-Systems.tritech-tfsurl-control.tritech-tfsurlcontrol-action","description":"Work Item fields to create url from","type":"ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form-control-group","targets":["ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form"],"properties":{"name":"tritech-tfsurl-control","uri":"index.html","height":90,"inputs":[{"id":"PreviousTFSServer","description":"The TFS server url that has the work item.","type":"WorkItemField","properties":{"workItemFieldTypes":["String"]},"validation":{"dataType":"String","isRequired":true}},{"id":"TFSCollection","description":"The original tfs collection name","type":"WorkItemField","properties":{"workItemFieldTypes":["String"]},"validation":{"dataType":"String","isRequired":true}},{"id":"TfsTeamProject","description":"Original TFS project name","type":"WorkItemField","properties":{"workItemFieldTypes":["String"]},"validation":{"dataType":"String","isRequired":true}},{"id":"TfsWorkItemId","description":"Original work item id","type":"WorkItemField","properties":{"workItemFieldTypes":["Integer"]}}],"::Attributes":16,"::Version":"0.1.20"}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I note that no target in the contribution, have your tried to add the  target ? Extension points : https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/targets/overview

Comment: I have a target of ms.vss-work-item-web.work.item.form

Comment: I'm thinking the issue is that I am not retrieving the value of the field, is there a method to get the fields values I'm missing? 'WitService.WorkItemFormService.getService().then(
            (service) => {
                Q.spread<any, any>( not sure what goes here? )'

Comment: Refer to this code to get field value. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-workitem-extension#javascript-sample. On the other hand, I don't find the element with urlcontrol id, which element use urlcontrol id?

Comment: Where do you want to show the URL and do the four fields already exist in the work item?

Comment: I want to put the url in a group on the work item, the group is a tab group on the form, the fields do exist and some have data, I added an control.ts page and moved most of the logic to it. I updated my original post with that info.

Comment: Do you want to save the URL as a field or just want to show the URL in the work item?

Comment: I just want to show the url on the form, I'vw migrated many tfs servers into one, this url is just pointing to the original work item on another server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using static values and got it working.

```js
var Provider = () => {
        this.ServerfieldName = "Source.Server"; 
        this.CollectionfieldName = "Source.Collection";  
        this.ProjectfieldName = "Source.Project";  
        this.WorkItemIdfieldName = "Source.Id";  
        this._view = View;

        return{
                onLoaded: (WorkItemLoadedArgs: ExtensionContracts.IWorkItemLoadedArgs) => {
            var deferred = Q.defer();
            
            WorkItemFormService.getService().then(
            (service) => {
                Q.spread<any, any>(
                    [service.getFieldValue(this.ServerfieldName),service.getFieldValue(this.CollectionfieldName),
                    service.getFieldValue(this.ProjectfieldName),service.getFieldValue(this.WorkItemIdfieldName)],
                                        (server: string, collection: string, project: string, workitemId: number) => {
                                        
                                        var data =(`${server}/${collection}/${project}/_workitems#_a=edit&id=${workitemId}`);
                                        if(server){
                                            this._view = new View(data);
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            $('body').empty().append("This is the original Work Item");
                                        }
                                        
                    })
                    .catch(function (e) {deferred.reject(e)} 
                ); 
                return deferred.promise;  //.then(null);
            }
        )}

    }    
};
```

and used a view,

```js
/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />
export class View {    

    constructor(public value:string) {
        
            var Container = $("<div role='link'> </div>");
            Container.addClass("Container");
            Container.attr('tabindex', '0');
            var rdiv = $("<div/>").addClass("rightDiv");
            var ldiv = $("<div/>");
            var help = $("<span></span>").text("Original Tfs work item ");

            var a = $("<a> </a>");
            a.attr("href", value);
            a.attr("target", "_blank");
            a.text("here.");
            help.append(a);
            ldiv.append(help);
            Container.append(rdiv);
            Container.append(ldiv);
            $('body').empty().append(Container);
        
    }
    
}
```